# Comprehension of a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

The output of the following Java code snippet is 10, but I don't understand why.

```
public class CodeComprehension {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
                count++;
    System.out.println(count);      
}
}
```

The `int` variable `count` appears in none of the three `for` loops. In my opinion the output should be 1.

Comment: The `count` variable is increased in the innermost `for-loop`. You should take a look at the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Add a System.out.print in the innermost for loop that prints i, j, and k. That might help you understand.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that count counts in every three loops the increments of the i, j and k variables?

Comment: @ryan careful with that suggestion though, keep in mind that this code lacks the necessary curly braces and the OP already is confused about what happens "inside a loop" given the fact that he thinks count++ is not inside any loop and is executed once (to become 1).

Comment: @Gimby, you are right. If you add the System.out.print, per my suggestion, you'll need opening and closing curly braces.

Comment: Try to write down each iteration with the values of `i`, `j`, `k` and `count` in a table. Iterative codes are simple to check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to go ahead and add an answer to prevent any further confusion. The suggestion to basically self-answer this question is to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        System.out.println("I-LOOP: I: "+  i + ", COUNT: " + count);

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {

            System.out.println("  J-LOOP: I: "+  i + ", J: " + j + ", COUNT: " + count);

            for(int k=0;k<j;k++) {
                // this is the code actually inside the loop(s)
                count++;
                System.out.println("    K-LOOP: I: "+  i + ", J: " + j + ", K: " + k + ", COUNT: " + count);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("END COUNT: " + count);      
}
```

What I did here is add some curly braces to the for-loops to make it a lot more visual what happens "inside" each loop. If you compile and run this version of the code you should see a whole lot of lines for each and every iteration of each and every loop. Hopefully when you see those individual i, j and k values for each iteration, it will be easier to wrap your head around how the flow of the code is when you have nested loops.

There are two main things to take away from this;

- System.out.println() is the best debugging and comprehension tool you have. Don't use it, **abuse it**.
- use curly braces in loop statements, always. Code is easier to read, and it takes away any possibility for making mistakes.

Here is the output:

```
I-LOOP: I: 0, COUNT: 0
I-LOOP: I: 1, COUNT: 0
  J-LOOP: I: 1, J: 0, COUNT: 0
I-LOOP: I: 2, COUNT: 0
  J-LOOP: I: 2, J: 0, COUNT: 0
  J-LOOP: I: 2, J: 1, COUNT: 0
    K-LOOP: I: 2, J: 1, K: 0, COUNT: 1
I-LOOP: I: 3, COUNT: 1
  J-LOOP: I: 3, J: 0, COUNT: 1
  J-LOOP: I: 3, J: 1, COUNT: 1
    K-LOOP: I: 3, J: 1, K: 0, COUNT: 2
  J-LOOP: I: 3, J: 2, COUNT: 2
    K-LOOP: I: 3, J: 2, K: 0, COUNT: 3
    K-LOOP: I: 3, J: 2, K: 1, COUNT: 4
I-LOOP: I: 4, COUNT: 4
  J-LOOP: I: 4, J: 0, COUNT: 4
  J-LOOP: I: 4, J: 1, COUNT: 4
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 1, K: 0, COUNT: 5
  J-LOOP: I: 4, J: 2, COUNT: 5
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 2, K: 0, COUNT: 6
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 2, K: 1, COUNT: 7
  J-LOOP: I: 4, J: 3, COUNT: 7
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 3, K: 0, COUNT: 8
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 3, K: 1, COUNT: 9
    K-LOOP: I: 4, J: 3, K: 2, COUNT: 10
END COUNT: 10
```